# Show ul elements one by one

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I have div block with ul list inside. And depending on the number of items div height getting bigger.
And if the last item is not fit of div max-height it just cut it which is not very good(pic-1).
How to scroll per one element and if last item does not fit of div max-height hide it below(pic-2)?

PIC-1 https://i.ibb.co/0Bwnp02/Screenshot-9.png 
PIC-2 https://i.ibb.co/jvmX9HN/Screenshot-10.png

```
<ul>
<li class="table-elem">
<p class="info-step">-1-</p>
<p class="info-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
mollitia id neque?</p>
</li>
...
</ul>
```

Comment: Ignoring the fact that showing a partial element to indicate that there's more content to scroll to is actually good UX. That said, do you want this to be solved with CSS only, or is a JavaScript solution also acceptable? Also, you want the scroll behavior to be affected, or the container height so that it only shows whole list items at once?

Comment: @Kriem,Js can also be used. Not whole list, just next list element which did not fit.

Comment: @Kriem, I'm probably not expressing my opinion correctly :)